# How to get event if someone click outside the body of pop screen in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to get event if some user click outside the body of pop up screen .Here is my fiddle .If user click header button (first button setting i) it show pop up screen .how if user click out side the pop up i need to show a alert .how to show that?

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/3yG9E/

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
    <h1>
        Case Information</h1>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div>
        <img src="img/Documents.png" /></div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="text-12" style="text-align: top; margin-left: 0px;">
            Case Name:</label>
        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h">
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="text-12" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 0px;">
            Case Date:</label>
        <!--input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h"  -->
        <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}' />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="textarea-12">
            Textarea:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="text-12" class="caseTextArea_h"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't click outside the popup/popup container as there is a div covering the whole screen. You can attached events to that div this way.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3yG9E/9/)**

```js
$('.ui-popup-screen').on('click', function () {
 // do something
});
```